# Offset printing array keys in an associative object array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a query that returns data from a database and stores the data in an array called `$array`.

Using a `print_r($array)` I receive data like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Item1] => 1
            [Item2] => 1
            [Item3] => 1
            [Item4] => 'Az'
            [Item5] => 222
            [Item6] => 223
            [Item7] => 21
            [Item8] => 22
        )
)
```

I've found I can return the keys `Item1` to `Item8` using:

```
foreach ($array[0] as $key => $a){
  echo '<pre>', $key, '</pre>';
}
```

**However I'd only like to return from Item4 to the end of the array. (remove the first 3 items)**

Note that query sometimes returns multiple rows i.e. `$array[0]`, `$array[1]` but `$array[0]` will always exist if there's a result. I only need to get the keys from the array once as I'd like to use them as column headings in the table they are displayed in.

I would prefer a `foreach()` situation as I would only like to output as many columns as are present.

I've tried looking at `array_slice()` but I couldn't seem to get it to work, my efforts are displayed below:

```
$sliced =  array_slice($prices[0], 3, $preserve_keys = true);
foreach ($sliced as $key => $value){
  echo '<pre>'.$key.'</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution to Your problem lays deeper than You are trying to solve it.**

If the DB query returns an array with indexes 1..10 but You only want to display the data from index 4..10 **then what You really need** is to change the DB query to return only these columns 4..10.

So basically instead of executing this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1
```

You need to execute query such this:

```sql
SELECT col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10
FROM table1
```

Comment: Well that was a silly mistake made by me when I first made the query, I'm glad you pointed that out

Answer (score 1):

As you mention **"i would prefer a foreach solution..."**, you can simply increment a counter, and not output anything until the counter has reached the required value:

```
$count = 0
foreach ($array[0] as $key => $a){
  $count++;
  if($count > 3){
     echo '<pre>', $key, '</pre>';
  }
}
```

Comment: equally valid, I like the thinking

Answer (score 1):

Transform your `stdClass` object into array and use `array_slice`.

```
$neededItems = array_slice((array)$array[0], 4, null, true);
```

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted! Thanks so much

Comment: @Adam, you are welcome! Do not forget rate answer, if he helped you